# WCF transport security with encryption

Tags: wcf, security

I have client server application which using WCF service with Transport security mode and NetTCP binding. I heard like Transport security is best for local intranet, not for internet. Now my scenario is I need to access WCF service over internet (from another country), but dont want to use Message security (cause it need to purchase and install certificate on server and each client). I want to use Transport security and also encrypt my data, so no one can hack it from internet.

So please someone guide me how can I encrypt my data with Transport security ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Transport is just SSL, so after the initial setup on the host and client sides, there's really nothing special to it. SSL will encrypt all the bytes starting at byte 0 and only the host that distributed the public key portion of the SSL cert will be able to decrypt the transmission since it and only it should have the private key part of the certificate.

SSL does present some potential problems if you have a load balancer or proxy fronting your service - i.e. if the proxy or LB server didn't begin the SSL transmission, it won't know what to do with the inbound message. But SSL encryption can be offloaded to a LB or proxy, so there are ways around that.

Here's a link to a stackoverflow question about SSL over WCF
[Enable SSL for my WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425978/enable-ssl-for-my-wcf-service)

Comment: As an aside, in Net.TCP, message security is actually *also SSL*. In message security, the Net.TCP binding does an SSL negotiation to negotiate the secure session. It is just hidden from view. Sweet design!

Comment: @Brian : Thanks for reply. But tell me if I go for Transport security then my data is secured or not ? (i.e it can be hacked from internet or not)

Comment: Yes, secured. SSL=Transport so someone sniffing the wire won't be able to read the transmission.

Comment: But in this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966126/is-transport-security-a-bad-practice-for-the-wcf-service-over-the-internet. It says like "you cannot guarantee a complete chain of secure connections over an arbitrary number of intermediate hops when you're dealing with an internet connection"

Comment: Well, I guess you'd better invent a better and more secure encryption method than SSL.